# Jquery replace not working for inner strings

Tags: jquery

I need to replace `|||` from all the input fields using jquery. But it is only replacing the first item. I need to use regex but I don't know how to add that to the string.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#layerPaper").children("div").each(function() {
        $val = $(this).children('input:text');
        $val.val($val.val().replace('|||', '\"'));
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are some different valid interpretations of your question. What do you mean by *"it is only replacing the first item"*? Do you mean that each input may have more than one `|||`? Or does it refer to the fact that in each `<div>` element  you're only using the value of the first `<input>` element.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean there are multiple instances of '|||' in an element then the `replace` you want is:

```
replace(/\|\|\|/g, '\"'));
```

Comment: `/\|{3}/g`, too. (Same number of characters, but arguably more legible. ;-)

Comment: @Brad, you're right of course, for only a few characters I prefer to show each one, but if there are say more than 5, or if, like here, the character has to be escaped, the "{n}" format is more legible.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#layerPaper > div > input:text").val(function(i,val){ 
    return val.replace('|||', '\"');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Brad. jQuery sure has some nice tricks for shortening code.

Comment: The code was replacing the ||| with the string function(i,val){ 
    return val.replace('|||', '\"'); Please let me know what is wrong

Comment: @dotnetrocks: That's very strange. What version of jQuery are you using? To pass a function, you'll need jQuery 1.4 or later.

Comment: I am using the older version ver 1.3.Thanks for correcting that.I will try it using the latest ver.

Comment: @dotnetrocks: You're welcome. I think I misunderstood your question initially. I didn't realize you potentially had more than one `|||` in an `<input>` element. The regex solution @Neil gave (or the comment from Brad below his answer) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex, I think your problem lies in the following:

```
$val.val($val.val().replace('|||', '\"'));
```

The `.val()` function only works on the first element found. You can switch this by using `$.each` though, fairly simply:

```
$(this).children('input:text').each(function(i,e){
  $(e).val($(e).val().replace('|||','"'));
});
```

Comment: Using a function callback would be even nicer.

Comment: @lonesomeday: I agree, but just want showing where the error was and how to solve. Wasn't going too deeply in to refactoring. Besides, @patrickdw did so for me. ;-)